# Firefox 29: HTTP "Content-Type" of "binary/octet-stream" is not supported

Tags: firefox, amazon-s3, html5-audio

Ever since Firefox 29 came out, my S3 bucket audio files have stopped working. When I use an `<audio>` element pointing to my S3 file, I get the following error:

```
HTTP "Content-Type" of "binary/octet-stream" is not supported. Load of media resource https://aaabbbdddccc.cloudfront.net/song.mp3 failed.
```

My files do still work in the latest versions of Chrome and Safari.

The only meta data in S3 that I have for the file is:

```
Content-Type: binary/octet-stream
```

It does work in Firefox if I change the `Content-Type` to `audio/mpeg`.

So my question is, am I behind the times and need to make a change to my `Content-Type` meta data to now support Firefox (and maybe other future browser upgrades)?

Or is this a bug that they need to fix and I need to find a workaround in the interim (like changing `Content-Type` to `audio/mpeg`?

Comment: You should always send the correct mime-type which for MP3 files is `audio/mpeg` See [RFC3003](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3003) or the [IANA list](http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml)

Comment: Thanks Mike. Looks like I have some work to do! Appreciate your help :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @Mike W mentioned in the comments, you need to always send the correct mime-type. I will do this from now on.

The mime-type I ended up using was `audio/mpeg`.

Comment: Can you please include the correct mime-type in your answer for future readers?